# How to debug "Error in data.frame" when using ds function in distance package?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am attempting to use the ds function in the distance package in Rstudio to get a density estimate from some point-count data I gathered. Dataset contains 7 replications of 34 point locations throughout 6 different cover types. Buffer radii were different depending on the cover type. A buffer distance was set at 75 meters for woody cover types with less visibility (ESF, MF, and SS) and 125 meters for more open cover types with grater visibility (ESG, AG, and LSG). When I originally tried running a model, I had the whole dataset in one file, but I believe the package didn't like that I had two different "Area" values for the 2 different buffer types. I then split the dataset into two files, one for the 75m buffered points and another for the 125m points, to try and run the models separately. When I ran the 125m dataset, the model failed to converge, but when I ran the 75m dataset I get "Error in data.frame(Region.Label = names(Effort.by.region), CoveredArea = CoveredArea,  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0"
I have realized that this package is picky about how the data is formatted in regards to column names, but I believe I have done it correctly. All columns in the dataset have the same number of rows and vice-versa.

Here are links to the two datasets:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZtcqXhqa6UnTUDqOsIobRVUc0M6E14qB/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wiYIWuAPtfODmlkYMJZnUXqQO3yEnA9Z/view?usp=sharing

and here is the code I'm using:

```r
library(Distance)
Rap<-read.csv("CountData_reorg_only75.csv")
table(Rap$Sample.Label)

#Plotting distance
hist(Rap$distance, xlab = "m", main = "Rap point counts")

#Setting units
units<-convert_units("meter", "NULL", "hectare")

Rap.hn<-ds(data = Rap, key = c("hn"), adjustment = NULL, transect = "point", convert_units = units)
summary(Rap.hn)
```

As mentioned above, I tried running the 125m dataset as well and did not get the same error but instead got an error stating the model failed to converge. As far as I can tell the formatting between the two datasets is identical. I've been researching the error message but nothing I've found seems to apply to my scenario. I'm new at asking questions on here so if I am leaving out any vital information please let me know!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but played around with it a little. Could it be that you need to have a region_table in order to use the point transect?

Comment: There's a funny aspect of your data - the largest count frequencies are at the farthest distance. The referenced journal article (https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v089i01) requires non-increasing. If you want to get the detection function only, you can use only the distance data, `Rap.$distance` and that will work, but only if you truncate your data, e.g. `truncation = 120,` for the 125 meter data. So, as I commented earlier, you do seem to need a region_table for the density estimate, but you can get the detection function with just the distances. Please update us if you make progress!

Comment: The study site that this data was collected on is rather small (~4500 acres) and landcover types are highly fragmented and heterogenous. Due to this I had to reduce buffer radii to the 125 m and 75 m distances to prevent overlap while still allowing for sufficient sampling points throughout each landcover type. With the birds of prey I was sampling they were most often first spotted outside of the buffer ring and then flew within the buffer. This is why observation distances are concentrated at the buffer distance.

Comment: For sampling points with a 125 m buffer distance I recorded observations out to 500 m but only included data recorded at or within 125 m in the dataset that I'm trying to analyze and get a density from. Same thing occurred at sampling points with a 75m buffer ring but I recorded observations out to 300 m during the data collection. Would I better off including the entire dataset in analyses, but instead truncating to the buffer distances? I'm also unsure what you mean by region_table? I have a region.label column which is consistent across the dataset due to only one region being sampled.

Comment: My knowledge is very limited, just what I gleaned from the package and the journal article. But, yeah, I think the model relies on those farther distances. The examples for the `ds` function show how they are limited without the region table. If you are trying to calculate abundance, the second example states you need to supply the region, sample and observation tables. Sorry, I don't know what all that means.